# Table 'test.grouped' doesn't exist

Tags: sql

I working on a SQL question on leetcode.com. Here is the data tables used:

Table: Product

```
+--------------+---------+
| Column Name  | Type    |
+--------------+---------+
| product_id   | int     |
| product_name | varchar |
| unit_price   | int     |
+--------------+---------+
```

product_id is the primary key of this table.

Table: Sales

```
+-------------+---------+
| Column Name | Type    |
+-------------+---------+
| seller_id   | int     |
| product_id  | int     |
| buyer_id    | int     |
| sale_date   | date    |
| quantity    | int     |
| price       | int     |
+------ ------+---------+
```

This table has no primary key, it can have repeated rows.
product_id is a foreign key to Product table

The question is writing an SQL query that reports the best seller by total sales price, If there is a tie, report them all.

Here is my solution:

```sql
Select *
From (Select seller_id,sum(price) as total
     from sales
     group by seller_id) as grouped

where grouped.total = (Select max(grouped.total)
                     From grouped)
```

In theory, this should work, I think. But I get this error:

Table 'test.grouped' doesn't exist

Can anyone help me figure out why I get this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot refer to a table alias as a table.  In this case, though, I would recommend window functions:

```
select *
from (Select seller_id, sum(price) as total,
             rank() over (order by sum(price) desc) as seqnum
      from sales
      group by seller_id
     ) s
where seqnum = 1;
```